# Conditional reduce

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to reduce a variable number of elements (or slices) of an array multiple times, and put the result into a new array. Kind of like a masked `np.apply_along_axis`, but we stay in `numpy`

For example, to reduce by mean:

```py
to_reduce = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]).astype(np.bool8)
arr = np.array([
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [1.0, 2.0, 4.0],
    [2.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    [2.0, 2.0, 4.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]])
```

I want:

```py
np.array([
    [1.5, 2.0, 3.5],
    [1.5, 1.0, 3.5],
    [1.33333, 1.33333, 3.0],
    [1.5, 2.0, 3.5]])
```

The slow way would be:

```py
out = np.empty((4, 3))
for j, mask in enumerate(to_reduce):
    out[j] = np.mean(arr[mask], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple and efficient way with `matrix-multiplication` -

```
In [56]: to_reduce.dot(arr)/to_reduce.sum(1)[:,None]
Out[56]: 
array([[1.5       , 2.        , 3.5       ],
       [1.5       , 1.        , 3.5       ],
       [1.33333333, 1.33333333, 3.        ],
       [1.5       , 2.        , 3.5       ]])
```